# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)= nx/(n^2x^2+1)$

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I am trying to find whether $f_n(x)= nx/(n^2x^2+1)$ is uniformly convergent or not.

I found that the pointwise limit was $0$ except for $x=1/n$. Can I then say that $f$ is uniformly convergent on $(-\infty,-a) \cup (a,\infty)$ for all $a>0$ so that, for $n$ large enough, I cannot take $1/n$ because it would be less than $a$, and then I always have that $|f_n(x)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Asserting that the pointwise limit of a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of functions from $\Bbb R$ into $\Bbb R$ is some $f(x)$ unless $x=\frac1n$ makes no sense, since $\frac1n$ is not a fixed number. Besides, for *every* real number $x$ you do have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{n^2x^2+1}=0$. So, your sequence converges pointwise to the null function.

However, since $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):f_n\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac12$, you know that $\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\bigl|f_n(x)-0\bigr|\geqslant\frac12$, and therefore the convergence is *not* uniform. Otherwise, you would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\Bbb R}\bigl|f_n(x)-0\bigr|=0$.

Comment: Does the inequality between the $\sup$ and $1/2$ follow from the fact that the supremum is greater than any of “the” elements?

Comment: Yes: if $S$ is a non-empty set of real numbers and $x\in S$, then $\sup S\geqslant x$.

Comment: Great, very nice answer! Upvoted.

Comment: I see now. I agree but in this case we have uniform continuity on (a,+inf), right ?

Comment: Yes, we do. Because, if $n$ is such that $\frac1n\leqslant a$, then $\sup_{x\geqslant a}|f_n(x)|=\frac{na}{n^2a^2+1}$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{na}{n^2a^2+1}=0$.